# How to query sql server database programatically, which is currently accessible using citrix receiver

Tags: citrix

We are currently accessing a SQLServer database through citrix receiver. On clicking on SSMS Icon in citrx XENAPP website, an ICA file is being downloaded. On click of that ICA file, SSMS is getting opened. I am running queries using this SSMS manually.

We would like to run these queries programatically. Is there any possible way? I am ready to use any programming language.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how the Database server instance is setup, how the server that it lives on is setup, and how the network is setup. You would need to speak with whomever is in charge of administration of the database server and ask them for direct access instead of access through the Citrix environment.

I work for a healthcare company, and we contract our EHR hosting to another company.  We connect to it through a Citrix environment similar to what you are describing. Because the contract company runs the data servers we are only able to access the SSMS through the Citrix environment.  This helps to ensure that our medical records are safe by limiting outside access to our EHR and PM databases.  I suspect that this is the case with your situation, but that is something that you will need to discuss with the people who are in charge of access to the data source.