# Is there a way to use Python to access Citrix Receiver, containing SQL database?

Tags: python, sql, citrix

[How to query sql server database programatically, which is currently accessible using citrix receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37466105/how-to-query-sql-server-database-programatically-which-is-currently-accessible)

Similar to this question...but I'm trying to use Python to write SQL queries, but I'm having trouble because Citrix Receiver is in the way.

Do I have to ask for direct database connection? Or is there another way around this?

Comment: Easiest way to test is install SSMS on your local machine and try to connect to the remote one. My experience with Citrix is that this will most likely not work.